# postgres partition data record assignment

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

It is possible in PostgreSQL 11 to display the partition table for each row in the table? Well, it's clear that the assignment of partitions is always known by the declarative definition but is there any way to get this information programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by using the [system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) `tableoid`:

```
select *, tableoid::regclass as partition_name
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c578a75b813c574a0fb59ffd6c51559f)